# ClassNotFoundException Java JApplet

Tags: java, html, swing, classnotfoundexception, japplet

I've been searching all over Stackoverflow and found out the problem seems to be, the path to the class is not correct. (I tried to tweak around my code, but it still gives me  ClassNotFoundException) The purpose of this code is to, let a user click on the list, then it will redirect them to a website.This is also pratice training from thenewboston.

Java:

```
  package webApplet;

  import java.applet.AppletContext;
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.List;
  import javax.swing.JApplet;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JList;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
  import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

  public class Applet extends JApplet {

    HashMap webInfo;
    List<String> name;
    JList list;

    public void init() {

    webInfo = new HashMap();
    name = new ArrayList();

    populate();
    add(new JLabel("please click on a website"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    list = new JList(name.toArray());
    list.addListSelectionListener(
    new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

            Object object = list.getSelectedValue();
            URL url = (URL) webInfo.get(object);
            AppletContext browser = getAppletContext();
            browser.showDocument(url);
        }
    });
    add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void populate() {

    URL url;
    String title;
    String address;
    int counter = 0;

    title = getParameter("title" + counter);

    while (title != null) {


        try {
            address = getParameter("address" + counter);
            url = new URL(address);
            webInfo.put(title, url);
            name.add(title);

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }
    counter++;
    title = getParameter("title" + counter);

 }
}
```

html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <applet code= "webApplet.Applet.class" width = "500" height = "250">
        <param name= "title0" value = "thenewBoston.org">
        <param name= "address0" value = "http://thenewboston.org">
        <param name= "title1" value = "Awesome forum!">
        <param name= "address1" value = "http://tnbforum.com/">
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
 Java Plug-in 10.25.2.16
 Using JRE version 1.7.0_25-b16 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
 User home directory = C:\Users\tin

 c:   clear console window
 f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
 g:   garbage collect
 h:   display this help message
 l:   dump classloader list
 m:   print memory usage
 o:   trigger logging
 q:   hide console
 r:   reload policy configuration
 s:   dump system and deployment properties
 t:   dump thread list
 v:   dump thread stack
 x:   clear classloader cache
 0-5: set trace level to <n>
```

under the error it has this :
"webApplet.Applet.class"

This is the flow of my files :

```
  website ----> 
               source packages----->
                              webApplet---->
                                          - Applet.java
                                          - bucky.html
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you have your html next to java file not class file. find the directory of the class file and put the html file in there.

class file has extension Applet.class not Applet.java

so in your case, your class file may be under webApplet/bin/classes

Comment: Shouldn't the applet be located in the source packages folder that holds the webApplet folder?

Comment: thats .java file, class file is usually under bin

Comment: Yes, then the bin folder, but not the folder that holds the class file since that is too high in the package. Regardless, better to just jar up the class file.

Answer (score 1):

It the `Applet.class` ends up in the same place as `Applet.java` (please choose better class names BTW, even `TestApplet01` makes it explicit that we are not referring to `java.applet.Applet`), then the `bucky.html` as seen needs to be in the parent directory.

```
  website ----> 
               source packages----->
                                  - bucky.html
                              webApplet---->
                                          - Applet.java
                                          - Applet.class
```

---

As to the HTML.  Change:

```html
<applet code= "webApplet.Applet.class" width = "500" height = "250">
    <param name= "title0" value = "thenewBoston.org">
    <param name= "address0" value = "http://thenewboston.org">
    <param name= "title1" value = "Awesome forum!">
    <param name= "address1" value = "http://tnbforum.com/">
</applet>
```

to..

```html
<applet code= "webApplet.Applet" width = "500" height = "250">
    ...
</applet>
```

The `code` attribute should be the fully qualified name of the class. While `webApplet/Applet.class` might be an href to a class, and `webApplet.Applet` is the FQN, `webApplet.Applet.class` is just ..wrong.  Tolerated, but wrong.

Comment: I updated my code, it is still giving me the same error exception.

Comment: *"I updated my code.."*  Code?  HTML is mark-up.  The fix I suggested is about moving the HTML, not 'coding'.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the Applet.class file is not in classpath. If you are not using any IDE, then you may need to manually compile the Applet.java file:

```
// Assuming the Applet.java is in current directory and Java is setup fully.
prompt> javac Applet.java
```

This will create the Applet.class file as webApplet/Applet.class. here webApplet is a folder.

Jar the complete webApplet/Applet.class file as

```
jar -cvf applet.jar webApplet/Applet.class
```

Add the jar path into the CLASSPATH environment variable value of the system.
See this on how to do that:
http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html

If you are using IDE like eclipse, it may help you to do that. In any way, the main thing is to make sure that the jar is in CLASSPATH, so that JVM could recognize the jar.

Comment: I am useing Netbeans, i'm still trying to figure out how to get Applet.class to get in the path. i've tried  putting my html in a folder with the class then openning it with Google chrome. (this does not solve any thing)

Comment: It has nothing to do with location of applet.class and html. Basically browser runs a tiny JVM inside which Applet class would run; and all JVM would look for CLASSPATH environment variable to find any class you are saying to load. You should approach step-by-step. First create the Jar, then add jar to CLASSPATH variable, and then load html in any browser. Lets first create the jar, and let me know once done.

Comment: Now, go to your machine's environment variable setup section. To set an environment variable permanently in Windows (so that it is available to all the Windows' processes), start the "Control Panel" ⇒ "System" ⇒ (Vista/7/8) "Advanced system settings" ⇒ Switch to "Advanced" tab ⇒ "Environment variables" ⇒ Choose "System Variables" (for all users) or "User Variables" (for this login user only) ⇒ check CLASSPATH variable is present or not? If present edit the same, if not create one.. Please post the content of CLASSPATH here.